# Notepad++ How to preserve CRLF upon saving

Tags: notepad++, newline

I've got a PHP file that I need to make a simple text change to.  I use FTP to copy from the linux server to my Win7 machine.  I open it with notepad++, turn on -view-show symbol-view all characters- and I can see CRLF and CR before and after each line.  But if I save the file and reopen the file in Notepad++, all of the CRLF's have been replaced with CR's.

How can I leave these CRLF's as they were when saving?

I am using Notepad++ 5.9.6.2

Encoding is set to ANSI.  Could the file be really be encoded in another format and this be the reason why it is stripping off the information?

Comment: What is the encoding for PHP file?

Answer (score 5):

Notepad++ normally detects the EOL format when you open the file and will keep that format even when you save the file. When you first open one of those files, go to `Edit>EOL Conversion` and see which option is grayed out. That will be the current line ending format used in the file, and if you want to use a different one from the list then you can select it there. It's possible that your file has mixed line endings, in which case NPP is probably normalizing the line endings to whatever it thinks is the right one for the file when you save.

As an aside, CR is the old Mac format, meaning you've either got something messing with your file, you're accidentally setting the format yourself somehow, or you're misusing the terminology. CR=carriage return=`\r`, LF=line feed=`\n`; Windows uses CRLF (`\r\n`), *nix and OSX use just LF (`\n`), and as stated MacOS used to use just CR (`\r`).

Comment: Additionally, FTP servers and clients can be configured to change line feeds on-the-fly.

Comment: I am using FileZilla v3.7.3 for FTP.  Is there a setting in filezilla to keep source line termination?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario While true (and a useful feature in GIT, and probably other source code repository servers/clients as well), I would think that wouldn't happen after the file has already been downloaded from the FTP server, as Notepad++ is a Windows program and thus I assumed the opening and saving was being done on the Win7 machine (not that someone couldn't use it on Linux via WINE or something similar, but there are already plenty of featureful *nix text editors so there'd be no reason to use NPP on such a machine).

Comment: @user3223999 - For a quick test go to "Transfer/ Transfer type" and select "Binary". There's a more general setting in preferences that sets the default value.

Comment: The programmer who wrote the code is not available today.  So I cannot say why it was coded so that there are both CRLF and CR.  It is PHP ajax code. I'd show a screen shot of the partial code if I could.  But when I edit it in Notepad++, it thinks that it is EOL Mac (as suspected) but I know that this programmer does not work on a Mac.  Add the end of each line of code, there is ;CR  then the next line always starts and only has CRLF and then the next line is just CR

Comment: If I do a binary transfer from the server to my win 7 machine, open in ++, then EOL says its a windows file and it "looks" normal to me.  Every line only has CRLF at the end when viewed in ++

Comment: @user3223999 Which would mean that FileZilla is converting CRLF to CRCRLFCR when transferring as text for some reason, which doesn't match any EOL format I know of (especially if the semicolon is added as well). Perhaps FileZilla does not properly analyze the newlines and assumes that if a text file comes from a Linux machine it will have LF line endings and thus prepends CR to any line ending it finds when transferring to a Windows machine, even if that line ending is a CR or an LF with a CR preceding it?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I seem to remember encountering a similar issue to what I just described in the past, but I can't remember what program it was with...

Comment: Filezilla was set to transfer "auto".  I transferred binary, edited the text in notepad++, transferred back in binary and tested the code and it appears to work fine.  When I did this process before, the code was broken.  So the file transfer from Filezilla does appear to have caused the issue.

Comment: @user3223999 And here's the reason why. https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Data_Type#Note So either you'll need to stick with binary mode, or you need to tell the person you work with to stop using CR+LF on the Linux server/not transfer the files to the server in binary mode.